# Regex to capture < not part of a \(...\) block

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to write a regex able to capture the first `<` character that is not part of a block starting with `\(` and ending with `\)`.

Some examples:

1. `foo1<foo2<fooooo3` should return the first `<` character.
2. `\(  gzgajk < lmklklml < \) foo1 < foo2` should return the third `<` character.
3. `\( sss < ljlj\) foo1 \(sqdzadz <jiojuioio\) foo2 < foo3` should also return the third `<` character.

I was looking to use positive look behind capability, but I'm not succeeding as positive  look behind should be of fixed length.

Any clue on the topic?

Comment: how would you define if found `<` is matched in right position? The value is `<` in any case

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for the comment. I was not aware of `*SKIP`and `*FAIL` keywords.

Comment: @chris85 Yes that works. You can move it to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the `\(` and its pair `\)` and anything in between (including `<`s) then ignore them with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, then match any `<` and you will now they aren't in the grouped pair. e.g.

```
\\\(.*?\\\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<
```

You can read more about this here, http://rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mQee39/1

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what you want to achive here, but have a look at this:

```
$subject ='\( sss < ljlj\) foo1 \(sqdzadz <jiojuioio\) foo2 < foo3';
preg_match ('#([<]{1})#', $subject , $matches, 0, (int)strrpos($subject,')'));
print_r($matches);
```

- strrpos() gets the position of the last `)`, if nothing found it starts from position 0
- the preg_match() will know look from this position for the next `<`.